# Calculating the number of occurrences of specific string values in a column

Tags: c#, sql

I have a sperate table for each person where I store information about its presence and absence.
I want to calculate the value of 'present' and 'absent' in a column 'attendance'
table name is "teacher name".

```
Database looked like this.
Time          Attendance
'2:30:30'   'Present'
'1:20:30'    'Present'
'4:10:30'    'Absent'[view of database in xampp][1]
'3:30:30'    'Present'
'2:32:30'    'Absent'
```

I want to calculate the number of occurrence of 'present' and 'absent'
so I can generate the salary according to it.
Is it possible?
Or I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Attendence, COUNT(*) FROM your_table
GROUP BY Attendence
```

Using LINQ, along the lines of:

```
.GroupBy (k => k.Attendence, (k, m) => new { Attendence = k, Count = m.Count() }
```

Per comment: If you need results horizontally rather than vertically, technically the proper way is to use [`PIVOT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot), but a quick and easy way is:

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE Attendence WHEN 'Present' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Present,
    SUM(CASE Attendence WHEN 'Absent' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Absent
    FROM your_table
```

Comment: hi sorry to bother you again can you please also tell me how to generate result using this statement in C#.Many thanks

Comment: @farhanbashir, Added. I'm editing on mobile,  so might have minor inaccuracies.

Comment: ok thank you. sorry but my question was wrong. i want to show the result in lables. Like when i run this query it gives me this kind of result.                            Count(*)      Attendence                                                                                                   Absent.           6                                                                                                       Present.          6                                                                                                 I want to show both present and absent and their result in 4 lables.